# Does a proof exist for the reflexive property (x=x)?

Tags: proof-explanation, formal-proofs

I have read an article suggesting that proofs or explanations do not exist for some very basic properties in math, including "$x$ is equal to $x$." A preliminary online search did not yield a satisfactory answer.

Does a mathematical proof or other explanation exist for the reflexive property in mathematics?

Comment: No; it is one of the [equality axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#First-order_logic_without_equality).

Answer (score 4):

A relation $R$ is reflexive if it satisfies $x R x$ for all $x$. It is up to you to show that a particular relation is reflexive.

That having been said, mathematics is bootstrapped by assumptions. These assumptions are called axioms. Long story short: you have to start from somewhere, and hence you have to assume *something*.

Answer (score 0):

That is one of the axioms of equality. An axiom in mathematics is a rule that helps you pin down what you're talking about - it defines the system you're using. Equality *has* to be reflexive because otherwise it wouldn't be equality.

Answer (score 0):

Equality behaves like a relation in many ways, and the entire concept of equivalence relations is built on trying to emulate it. But equality itself is *not a relation*. It is a defined piece of our logic, and the meaning of the statement "$x = y$" is that any property that is satisfied by $x$ is also satisfied by $y$, and vice versa, for a specific formal and rigorous definition of "property".

And clearly, for any reasonable definition of "property", including the conventional one used here, $x$ satisfies the same properties as $x$. So we get $x = x$.